# OpenCL-OpenGL interoperability (FBO texture as image source in OpenCL)

Tags: opengl, interop, opencl, fbo

I have tested OpenCL-OpenGL interoperability using Pixel Buffer Objects (for postprocessing OpenGL result image) and it's fine. But I always get errors if I use  texture, attached  as color component to Frame Buffer Object used for offsreen rendering. Are there any known problems using FBO textures as OpenCL Image buffers?
Errors may arise in calling clEnqueueAcquireGLObjects or in clEnqueueNDRangeKernel.

Comment: It would be helpful to include what errors you are getting, and also show how you are creating the FBO texture and the OpenCL object that is based on it.

Comment: Please can you provide the code, it would be helpful how you are sharing buffers between OpenCL and OpenGL.